Convert CSV file in an Symfony entity
I work with Symfony.
I have an example CSV format file that contains three rows using ";" as separator.
I need to convert it into a table with three rows, to do this I use the following code:

if (($gestor = fopen("importar.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    
    while (($datos = fgetcsv($gestor, 10000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
    
        $em = $entityManager;
        $entityMusic = new Fuente(); //This is your entity

        $entityMusic->setDiario($datos[0]); //Respective entity methods
        $entityMusic->setLink($datos[1]);
        $entityMusic->setPalabras($datos[2]);
        $entityMusic->setTitulo($datos[3]);
        $entityMusic->setContenido($datos[4]);
    
        $em->persist($entityMusic);
        $em->flush();
    }
}

When I run the code I get six rows in the table. The three rows of the CSV file are repeated twice.
Why do I get this result?

Try an $en-clear($entityMusic) after the flush

What is $en-clear?

Spelling error, sorry $em->clear($entityMusic)

Sorry RiggsFolly but not work

Problem solved: I only added the enclosure " to each field of the importar.csv file and now the records are not duplicated. The delimiter used is ;
I also added RiggsFolly's suggestion.
